# Concat named list of vectors

Tags: r, named, data-transform

I'd trying to figure out how to transform a named list where the values are also list in a named list where the value is the result of a concatenation of the values within a vector.

I do not know if I explain correctly or easily, so follow the example.

```
x <- list(A = c("e", "f", "g"), B = c("a", "b", "c"), C = c("m", "l", "w"))

#$A
#[1] "e" "f" "g"
#$B
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
#$C
#[1] "m" "l" "w"

named_list_concat <- function(data){ ... }

named_list_concat(x)

#$A
#[1] "efg"
#$B
#[1] "abc"
#$C
#[1] "mlw"
```

Comment: You can try `lapply(x, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ""))`.

Comment: @tmfmnk thanks, would you answer to I close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One base possibility:

```
lapply(x, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ""))

$A
[1] "efg"

$B
[1] "abc"

$C
[1] "mlw"
```

Or the same thing in a shortened form:

```
lapply(x, paste, collapse = "")
```